# How can I migrate my Cython code from Shapely 1.8 to Shapely 2.0?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, cython, shapely

I have some custom Cython code to detect if linestrings cross a prepared geometry.

In the migration from shapely 1.8 to 2.0, the following line segfaults:

```
result[i] = <np.uint8_t> GEOSPreparedIntersects_r(geos_handle, geom1, geom2)
```

The full Cython code is:

```py
#!python
#cython: language_level=3

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

cimport cython
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t
import shapely.prepared
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

__all__ = ['two_points_intersect_geom', "DTYPE"]

np.import_array()
DTYPE = np.float32

ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t

cdef extern from "geos_c.h":
    ctypedef void *GEOSContextHandle_t
    ctypedef struct GEOSGeometry
    ctypedef struct GEOSCoordSequence
    ctypedef struct GEOSPreparedGeometry

    GEOSCoordSequence *GEOSCoordSeq_create_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, unsigned int, unsigned int) nogil
    int GEOSCoordSeq_getSize_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, GEOSCoordSequence *, unsigned int *) nogil
    int GEOSCoordSeq_setX_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, GEOSCoordSequence *, int, double) nogil
    int GEOSCoordSeq_setY_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, GEOSCoordSequence *, int, double) nogil
    int GEOSCoordSeq_setZ_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, GEOSCoordSequence *, int, double) nogil
    GEOSGeometry *GEOSGeom_createLineString_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, GEOSCoordSequence *) nogil

    char GEOSPreparedIntersects_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, const GEOSPreparedGeometry *, const GEOSGeometry *) nogil
    char GEOSIntersects_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, const GEOSGeometry *, const GEOSGeometry *) nogil

cdef GEOSContextHandle_t get_geos_context_handle():
    # Note: This requires that lgeos is defined, so needs to be imported as:
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
    cdef uintptr_t handle = lgeos.geos_handle
    return <GEOSContextHandle_t> handle

cdef GEOSPreparedGeometry *geos_from_prepared(shapely_geom) except *:
    """Get the Prepared GEOS geometry pointer from the given shapely geometry."""
    cdef uintptr_t geos_geom = shapely_geom._geom
    return <GEOSPreparedGeometry *> geos_geom

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def two_points_intersect_geom(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] latlon, geometry):
    """
    Example:
        import numpy as np
        import cartopy.feature as cfeature
        from shapely.ops import unary_union
        from shapely.prepared import prep
        land = prep(unary_union(list(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m').geometries())))
        latlon = np.array([
            [[0, 0], [0, 10]],
            [[0, 0], [0, -10]],
        ], dtype=float)
        two_points_intersect_geom(latlon, land)
    """
    cdef GEOSCoordSequence *coord_sequence
    cdef GEOSPreparedGeometry *geom1
    cdef GEOSGeometry *geom2
    cdef double lat, lon
    cdef int n_point_pairs = len(latlon)
    cdef int seqSize = 2
    cdef int seqDim = 2
    cdef int i, j
    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=1, cast=True] result = np.empty(n_point_pairs, dtype=np.uint8)

    if not isinstance(geometry, shapely.prepared.PreparedGeometry):
        geometry = shapely.prepared.prep(geometry)

    geos_handle = get_geos_context_handle()
    geom1 = geos_from_prepared(geometry)
    for i in range(n_point_pairs):
        coord_sequence = GEOSCoordSeq_create_r(geos_handle, seqSize, seqDim)
        for j in range(2):
            lat = latlon[i][j][0]
            lon = latlon[i][j][1]
            d = GEOSCoordSeq_setX_r(geos_handle, coord_sequence, j, lat)
            d = GEOSCoordSeq_setY_r(geos_handle, coord_sequence, j, lon)
        geom2 = GEOSGeom_createLineString_r(geos_handle, coord_sequence)
        result[i] = <np.uint8_t> GEOSPreparedIntersects_r(geos_handle, geom1, geom2)
    return result.view(dtype=np.bool_)
```

The test for this code is:

```py
geom = Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]])
land = prep(geom)

latlon = np.array(
    [
        [[-0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]],
        [[10, 10], [20, 20]],
    ],
    dtype=DTYPE_CYTHON,
)
ret = two_points_intersect_geom(latlon, land)
self.assertListEqual([True, False], list(ret))
```

I am not sure why this code no longer works, because I am still using the `_geom` attribute rather than the depreciated `__geom__`.

I have tested that the seg fault is not coming from `geos_handle`, `geom2` or assigning to the result with `result[i] = <np.uint8_t>`. So it is coming from `geom1`.

I believe the problem is in the line:

```
cdef GEOSPreparedGeometry *geos_from_prepared(shapely_geom) except *:
    """Get the Prepared GEOS geometry pointer from the given shapely geometry."""
    cdef uintptr_t geos_geom = shapely_geom._geom
    return <GEOSPreparedGeometry *> geos_geom
```

However I cant find a reason, looking through Shapely and geos changes why this function will now fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rewrite `get_geos_context_handle` to make use of `shapely._geos.get_geos_handle` and access its `handle` attribute.

See [this file](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/blob/main/shapely/_geos.pxd) for the detailed implementation in Shapely 2+

Comment: Thanks, I just did `geos_handle = GEOS_init_r()` and then at the end of my code, called `GEOS_finish_r(geos_handle)`